# How to Execute/Run Scala project from command line which is built using SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I am making an basic app which will be used to run some HIVE scripts from local machine.

I am building the project using sbt so all the required jars are present in build.sbt and for running the app i will be giving it to users who will not have any sbt or development env. They will just Run the application to RUN our business requirements on HIVE.

Issue is once i sbt package the app into a jar file or (sbt-assembly for making Fat Jar) how to run it on command prompt. As other users will not be having SBT on their machines so they won't be able to run using 'sbt run', they will have to run the App which is packaged in a form of jar, From Command Prompt only.

So what will be the command for that. Like how to specify the Object with main function, how to define the jar what are the options ...

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using sbt-assembly for making jar,navigate to the jar location and try this in command prompt to run:

```
java -cp XXX-assembly.jar YYY
```

Here `XXX-assembly.jar` is your jar name and `YYY` is the main file name with package it is located.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Not through Jav i have to achieve this using Scala only

Comment: Scala also runs on JVM as java, so it doesn't matter

Comment: What if i am not making assembly jar..?? Then i think the users also need to have sbt setup ..?? Am i correct ..?

Comment: `java -jar XXX.jar` if you are not making assembly jar and no need of sbt setup for running executable jar.